# Cannot resolve external dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-sam-with-receiver:1.5.31 because no repositories are defined

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, buildsrc

Trying to add buildSrc to manage dependencies getting the following error:
Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

in the `build.gradle.kts` file after the plugins block to solve.